# Exception in assigning to CurrencyDecimalDigits in Globalization.NumberFormatInfo

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Globalization.NumberFormatInfo in vb code and trying to assign value to CurrencyDecimalDigits which is a member of this class:

```
  Dim a As Globalization.NumberFormatInfo
  a = New Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()
  Dim b As Integer = 4
  a.CurrencyDecimalDigits = b
```

In MSDN it's written that it is a read only member, though it is shown a code with assigning to it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimaldigits.aspx

Is there a way to assign value to CurrencyDecimalDigits?
Does anybody had this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: Found the solution, NumberFormatInfo is read only, therefore need to call clone() method when assigning to it:Dim a As Globalization.NumberFormatInfo
  a = New Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() a = a.Clone()
  Dim b As Integer = 4
  a.CurrencyDecimalDigits = b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, NumberFormatInfo is read only, therefore need to call clone() method when assigning to it:Dim a As Globalization.NumberFormatInfo a = New Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() a = a.Clone() Dim b As Integer = 4 a.CurrencyDecimalDigits = b